# Why is my repositoryPath ignored in Azure DevOps / TFS?

Tags: c#, tfs, azure-devops, continuous-integration, nuget

First of all, I have a NuGet.Config:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<configuration>
  <config>
    <add key="repositoryPath" value=".\ExternalReferences\Packages" />
      <solution>
        <add key="disableSourceControlIntegration" value="true" />
      </solution>
  </config>
</configuration>
```

In the root of my `dev` branch. It's job is, that every project in my `dev` branch restores the packages into `\dev\ExternalReferences\Packages`, which works fine localy.

Im trying to introduce Azure Pipelines via TFS (VisualStudio Team Services/DevOps) for my CI-Build.

However, TFS is restoring the packages into the wrong folder `\dev\packages` (where `\dev` is `D:\a\9\s\`) instead of `\dev\ExternalReferences\Packages`.

```
Acquired lock for the installation of Newtonsoft.Json 12.0.3
Installing Newtonsoft.Json 12.0.3.
Adding package 'Microsoft.Extensions.Logging.Abstractions.2.2.0' to folder 'D:\a\9\s\packages'
```

This breaks the build later (Which expects the `ExternalReferences\Packages`):

```
PrepareForBuild:
  Creating directory "bin\Release\".
  Creating directory "obj\Release\".
ResolveAssemblyReferences:
  Primary reference "Newtonsoft.Json, Version=12.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=30ad4fe6b2a6aeed, processorArchitecture=MSIL".
##[warning]C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio\2017\Enterprise\MSBuild\15.0\Bin\Microsoft.Common.CurrentVersion.targets(2110,5): Warning MSB3245: Could not resolve this reference. Could not locate the assembly "Newtonsoft.Json, Version=12.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=30ad4fe6b2a6aeed, processorArchitecture=MSIL". Check to make sure the assembly exists on disk. If this reference is required by your code, you may get compilation errors.
C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio\2017\Enterprise\MSBuild\15.0\Bin\Microsoft.Common.CurrentVersion.targets(2110,5): warning MSB3245: Could not resolve this reference. Could not locate the assembly "Newtonsoft.Json, Version=12.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=30ad4fe6b2a6aeed, processorArchitecture=MSIL". Check to make sure the assembly exists on disk. If this reference is required by your code, you may get compilation errors. [D:\a\9\s\Conwell.WebServices.Google\Conwell.WebServices.Google.csproj]
```

Any Idea how to make NuGet to restore to the correct directory?

I just created a standard Pipeline for the project type Asp.NET

[image: Nuget]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> Why is my repositoryPath ignored in Azure DevOps / TFS?

Since the nuget restore task restoring the packages into the wrong folder `\dev\package`s, it seems the settings `repositoryPath` in the `NuGet.Config` is ignored.

To resolve this issue, you could try to specify the `nuget.config` when you set the nuget restore task to make sure you have use the `NuGet.Config`:

[image]

Then my `nuget.config` looks like:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<configuration>
  <packageSources>
    <add key="AzureDevOpsFeed" value="https://pkgs.dev.azure.com/xxxn/_packaging/xxx/nuget/v3/index.json" />
    <add key="nuget.org" value="https://api.nuget.org/v3/index.json" />
  </packageSources>

  <config>
    <add key="repositoryPath" value=".\ExternalReferences\Packages" />
  </config>

</configuration>
```

Then, as test result, I could get the package in the folder `ExternalReferences\Packages`:

[image]

Hope this helps.

Comment: Thx. But the problem with this solution is, it is installing it into `Nuget\ExternalReferences` and not in `ExternalReferences` now :( Any Ideas?

Answer (score 0):

As a workaround I configured the directory directly:

Go to pipeline, and edit:

[image: Edit Pipeline]

Go to NuGet restore, Advanced and Destination Directory:

[image: Nuget Restore]

I am still open to options, which would respect the `NuGet.Config`.